# Thread does not end cleanly due to socket recv callback

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, send, recv

I am trying to close the socket and terminate the thread when shutdown handler callback is executed (I send SIGINT signal by CTRL+C)

**main**

```
from example import Example

if __name__ == '__main__':

    exmpl = Example()
    success = exmpl.connect('', 2000)
    
    if success:
        rospy.on_shutdown(exmpl.shutdown_handler)

        rospy.spin()
```

**imported class**

```
import socket
import threading

class Example(object):

    def connect(self, host='', port=2000):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.settimeout(10)
            self.sock.bind((host, port))
            self.sock.listen(1)
            self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
            self.sock.settimeout(None)

            self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.recv_msg)
            self.t.start()

            return True
        
        except Exception as e:
            return False
        
        except Exception as timeout:
            return False

    def recv_msg(self):
        while True:
            recv_msg = self.conn.recv(1024)
            print(recv_msg)

    def shutdown_handler(self):
        try:
            self.sock.close()
            self.t.join()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

In this application recv_msg is always executing because data are coming all the time. So, when I send SIGINT, shutdown handler starts and only executes the statement *sock.close()* but not *t.join()* and thread never ends

Comment: Check out the first answer to this question (same problem and same solution, except he's using UDP instead of TCP):   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912245/python-how-to-close-a-udp-socket-while-is-waiting-for-data-in-recv

Comment: Correct! Thank you for your answer